# CSS Wrapper Width

Tags: css

I'm attempting to change the wrapper width on a wordpress blog. It's currently set as following:

`#wrapper {
    width: 1146px;
    padding: 0 28px;
    margin: 0 auto;`

I would like to make the width 1050, however when I change the width pixels to 1050, it doesnt change the width of the wrapper, it just pushes the entire container to the right.

Am I missing something?

Here's a link to the blog if it helps [My Blog](http://www.beastlywild.com)

Comment: it's hard to know without seeing what other styles are being applied to the wrapper, can you use firebug to inspect what other styles may be affecting it?

Comment: There is probably another element surrounding wrapper. So you also need to shrink that. If you can provide a link it will be a lot easier to trouble shoot.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. [link](http://beastlywild.com)  @mrtsherman

Comment: When I inspect with Firebug, <div id="wrapper">
<header>
<div id="root"> comes up but I don't notice anything else under css affecting the width? Perhaps the "root"? width. I looked in there @ggreiner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems like this are usually the result of items *inside* of your #wrapper being too wide for the wrapper's width. I looked at the code on your homepage (saw the URL for your screenshot) and found the problem to be with the #root padding.

Change this:

```
#root {
width: 956px;
padding: 35px 95px;
background: #fff;
```

}

to this:

```
#root {
width: 956px;
padding: 35px 47px;
background: #fff;
```

}

Comment: Hey thanks. I think that worked! My navigation bar is too long know but I think I can just adjust the width under the navigation section ins CSS. I saw the "root" element in firebug but didn't realize it was the padding.

Comment: Thanks everyone! It's fixed thanks to your assistance and now I know a little more about CSS!

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
#wrapper { width: 1146px; padding: 0 28px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

with:

```
#wrapper { width: 1050px; padding: 0 28px; margin: 0 auto; overflow:hidden;}
```

good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I applied the change and it cut off the overflow on the right side of the wrapper but didn't quite change the width, so now the content is and wrapper are off center. See the before and after here: Before [link](http://www.beastlywild.com/before.jpg)  After [link](http://www.beastlywild.com/after.jpg)